# Getting a variable from a list of objects

Tags: c#, arrays, list, variables, object

How would you get a variable from each object in a list?

I've got this so far:

```
void SortList()
{
    int j = modules.Count;
    string[] titles = new string[j];

    for (int i = 0; i > modules.Count; i++)
    {
        titles[i] = 
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to get the variable "code" from each object in modules.

thanks.

Comment: what is modules? Is it a list, or array?,

Comment: Then: `modules[i].code`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implying modules is a list or an array,

```
void SortList()
{
    int j = modules.Count;
    string[] titles = new string[j];

    foreach (String title in modules)
    {
        titles[i] = title.code
    }
}
```

As stated by Cuong Le, you could also use [Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/bb548891.aspx) to get a shorter version (Depending of which .Net version you are on).

```
titles = modules.Select(x => x.code).ToArray();
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm trying that now but i get the error:     'stageManagement.Module.code is inaccessible due to its protection level'   --- Also your other way doesnt want to work either.

Comment: @Kennyist Well it depends. What is the protection level of the `code` field ? Does it have Get Set Accessors ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ with simple code with `Select` method:

```
titles = modules.Select(x => x.code).ToArray();
```